# How to make the text change accordingly to the JS variable?

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to make a counter number on the screen and two buttons (increase and decrease) which will increase/decrease the counter number.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Counter</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
    
</head>
<body style = "background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);">
    <center><h1 class="title">Counter</h1></center>
    <center><h1 class="counter" id="counter">0</h1></center>
    <center><button type="button" class="decrease_button" onclick="decrease()">Decrease</button></center>
    <center><button type="button" class="increase_button" onclick="increase()">Increase</button></center>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS code:

```
let counterEl = document.getElementById("counter")

function decrease(){
    let counter = document.getElementById('counter')
    counter = counter - 1
    console.log(counter)

    counterEl.innerHTML = counter;

}

function increase(){
    let counter = document.getElementById('counter')
    counter = counter + 1
    console.log(counter)

    counterEl.innerHTML = counter;
}
```

My CSS code:

```
.title {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(243, 242, 242);
    font-size: 60px;
    transform: translateY(0%);

}
.counter{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(243, 242, 242);
    /*color: rgb(67, 205, 67)  -   green*/
    /*color: rgb(217, 56, 56)  -   red*/
    font-size: 100px;
    transform: translateY(25%);
    opacity: 60%;
}
.decrease_button {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    transform: translateX(-150%);
    cursor: pointer;

}
.increase_button {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    transform: translateX(150%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

When I run the code and click Increase, the counter text changes to:
`[object HTMLHeadingElement]1`

And when I click Decrease, the counter text changes to:
`NaN`

Comment: remove this line **let counter = document.getElementById('counter')** as it isn't needed and it is causing you to overwrite your counter variable with the html element. Also, at the top above the functions declare your counter **let counter = 0;**

Comment: you using outdated and deprecated emthods. `<center>` is deprecated in HTML5 and centering elements should be done with `CSS`. Then`innerHTML` is slow (reparse of DOM) and poses a security risk (XSS). USe `textContent instead. Instead of `onclick` attributes as a trigger, an eventListener should be used. Last but not least, a variable can be increased with `variable++` or `variable--`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked and I now understand the reason my code wasn't working before.

Answer (score 0):

You're using outdated and deprecated methods. `<center>` is deprecated in HTML5 and centering elements should be done with CSS.

Then `innerHTML` is slow (reparse of DOM) and poses a security risk (XSS). More intelligent is to use the semantic correct `<output>` element and update the `value`.

Instead of `onclick` attributes as a trigger, an `eventListener` should be used. Last, a variable can be increased with `variable++` or `variable--`.

```js
let output = document.querySelector('#counter');
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(el =>
  // event Listener to check if a button is pressed + event delegation
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // get the id of the pressed button
    let button = e.target.id;
    //get the current counter
    let counter = output.value;
    // switch statement to increase or decrease the counter
    switch(button) {
      case 'increase': 
        counter++;
        break;
      case 'decrease':
        counter--;
        break;
    }
    // display an updated counter
    output.value = counter;
  })
)
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="counter">Counter: </label><output id="counter" value="0">0</output>
<button id="increase">Increase Counter</button>
<button id="decrease">Decrease Counter</button>
```